# Difference in Call Apply and Bind

Tags: javascript

Here is the piece of code I have wriiten

```
const counter = {
  count: 0,
  incrementCounter: function () {
    console.log(this);
    this.count++;
    },
};

document
  .querySelector(".btn")
  .addEventListener("click", counter.incrementCounter.bind(counter));
```

When ever I use bind it returns me the function with count increasing its value on every click but whenever I use apply or call it just return me the object once why is that? what is its behind the scene

Answer (score 0):

`bind()` just binds something as `this` when you call the function later. so it doesn't call the function.
`bind()` is something like this (as you seen it returns a function that uses `apply()` but doesn't call it):

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(ctx, ...args){
  const self = this;
  return function(...extraArgs){
    return self.apply(ctx, args.concat(extraArgs));
  }
}
```

`apply()` calls the function with particular `this` so you can see a side effect from the call in your case it's the incremented counter.